# Does accept_attributes_for have to be used with has_

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm reading http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html in the documentation and trying to figure out if the model that holds the "accepts_attributes_for" can only be used when it possesses a record or many records...

My background was in t-sql for a bit, so I'm struggling to use the "ruby magic"...as sometimes the magic is too vague, so I'm asking someone to spell out if this example below is allowed ... instead of this record using "has_many" or "owns", I'm using "belongs_to" as it's a cross link table.

```
class Postteam < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
   belongs_to :team

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't have to, but you do have to get the pluralisation matching. You currently have `belongs_to :post` (singular) but `accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts` (plural)...

that should either be `accepts_nested_attributes_for :post` (singular) to match

alternatively, use: `has_many :posts`

If by "crosslink table" you mean a join table (eg joining posts to teams) and the model actually has `post_id` and `team_id` then use the first example. You have `belongs_to` correctl for both post and team and you need to tell `accepts_nested_attributes_for` that it's only accepting attributes for a single post and a single team (thus use `:post` and `:team` respectively).

If you use a pluralised word eg `:posts` then Rails expects to be accepting a whole array of posts. If there is just one post. then use the singluar `:post`.

Rails' use of pluralisation is pretty intuitive, as long as you have been told the reason why it's there in the first place. :)

HOWEVER... Rails also has conventions for join-tables that I think you might be missing a little bit.
I cannot recommend strongly enough that you should read through the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) (not just the api doc) in order to understand Rails conventions before digging in. If you break from Rails conventions you will be fighting it ll the way. If you align yourself with Rails conventions - it will be a smooth and easy trip.

Comment: Let me break this into chunks so I can plus the things piece by piece .... `Rails use of pluralisation is pretty intuitive, as long as you have been told the reason why it's there in the first place. :) `  - I'm not finding the context of this ... just to confirm - the pluralization determines if it's an array being returned by the SQL?

Comment: On the matching - has_many to accepts_nested ... yes, ty - I gave up that demo, but that makes sense with the not pluralizing the second part if I don't do the first.

Comment: Pluralisation matches your intention. If you are intending there to be a single object, you use the singular. If you are intending it to be a set of ohbjects, you use the plural. Ie if your Widget has one doodad, you say "belongs_to/has_one :doodad" if your widget has a set of doodads, you use "has_many :doodads"